# eglfs on raspberry2 -- * failed to add service - already in use?

Tags: qt5, raspberry-pi2, qtquickcontrols2, archlinux-arm, eglfs

that's is my first post here.

I'd like to keep it short...

**Following problem:**

i want to run a qt5/qtquickcontrols2 application utilising the eglfs backend on a raspberry-pi 2b, accelerated by vc4, of course.
Ideally, it should run in kiosk mode and it definitely needs accelerated gl functionality.
To minimise problems, I tested with the command:

`LD_PRELOAD="/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so" qmlscene ./gallery.qml`

where gallery.qml is simply the widget preview example project from qt-creator (followed [these](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qt5-qpa-rpi-plugin/) instructions...).
I'm getting following error output:

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ LD_PRELOAD="/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so" qmlscene ./gallery.qml
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_brcm"
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_brcm"
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

I also tested the same running a crosscompiled binary - same error.
All but the last line come from verbose debugging output of qt5,
which i set via environment variable, details will follow.

**System / Environment:**

- raspberry-pi 2b
- qt-5.7.0
- Manjaro-ARM (based on Arch Linux ARM)
- all firmware stuff, tools, boot stuff, kernel are installed and up to date

Other settings...

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ uname -a
Linux Loki 4.4.28-1-MANJARO-ARM #1 SMP Sat Oct 29 21:01:09 CDT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

My config.txt

```
dtparam=audio=on
#hdmi_drive=2
avoid_warnings=2
disable_overscan=1
disable_splash=1
boot_delay=0

# activate raspi cam
start_x=1

# tuning gpu accel and memory usage
gpu_mem=320
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

My cmdline.txt

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw  rootwait console=tty1 selinux=0 quiet plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes
```

printenv gives following:

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=c1
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.0.100 43274 22
QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_brcm
OLDPWD=/home/manjaro
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=manjaro
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/manjaro
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/vc/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
PWD=/home/manjaro/opt
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/manjaro
LOGNAME=manjaro
QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.qpa.*=true
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.0.100 43274 192.168.0.107 22
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

You can see several Qt specific settings: debugging , using eglfs as default backend and the most interesting:
`QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_brcm` which means that broadcom eglfs plugin should be used. Along `eglfs_brcm` i tried `eglfs_kms` too (just out of curiosity):

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ export QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_kms
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ LD_PRELOAD="/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so" qmlscene ./gallery.qml 
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_kms", "eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_kms"
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_kms"
qt.qpa.input: udev device discovery for type QFlags(0x10)
qt.qpa.input: Found matching devices ("/dev/dri/card0")
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Found the following video devices: ("/dev/dri/card0")
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Using "/dev/dri/card0"
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Opening device "/dev/dri/card0"
qt.qpa.eglfs.kms: Creating GBM device for file descriptor 5 obtained from "/dev/dri/card0"
* failed to add service - already in use?
```

It seems to be neither a problem with the video core, nor a problem of the "stock" Qt of manjaro-arm. It simply says something could being blocked, but what? Any hints?

Overlays and drivers seem to work, glxgears achieved ~60FPS running on xfce4.
Following is interesting too:

```
[root@Loki gallery]# vcdbg log msg|& grep -v gpioman|grep -iv hdmi
001042.905: *** Restart logging
001043.889: Read command line from file 'cmdline.txt'
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw  rootwait console=tty1 selinux=0 nofb dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes
001409.425: Loading 'kernel7.img' to 0x8000 size 0x5ea25c
001413.076: Kernel trailer DTOK property says yes
001413.091: Kernel trailer DDTK property says yes
001415.514: Loading 'bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb' to 0x5f225c size 0x3bfc
001514.479: dtparam: audio=on
001567.591: Loaded overlay 'vc4-kms-v3d'
001836.841: Device tree loaded to 0x2effbc00 (size 0x430d)
005904.220: vchiq_core: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xd0400000, is_master = 1
005911.919: TV service:host side not connected, dropping notification 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0x00000010
007999.619: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 32, power enable gpio = 41
008000.339: camsubs: Camera not found
008000.377: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 32, power enable gpio = 41
008001.091: camsubs: Camera not found
008001.128: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 32, power enable gpio = 41
008001.844: camsubs: Camera not found
```

Looks pretty much like it should to me.

**I tried following things:**

I played around with gpu_mem split, tried values between 128 and 448.
Checking gpu mem looks as expected, but no effect on executing mentioned app.

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ vcgencmd get_mem gpu
gpu=320M
```

I also created following udev rule in order to fix an error I initially faced

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq",GROUP="video",MODE="0660"

[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ groups
wheel video storage power users
```

Without the mentioned udev rule, I'd get following error:

```
[manjaro@Loki gallery]$ LD_PRELOAD="/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so" qmlscene ./gallery.qml 
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys: ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: EGL device integration plugin keys (sorted): ("eglfs_brcm", "eglfs_kms", "eglfs_x11")
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Trying to load device EGL integration "eglfs_brcm"
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Using EGL device integration "eglfs_brcm"
* failed to open vchiq instance
```

Damn... I'm out of ideas now...
I'd appreciate every little hint which could help...

**Please do not:**

- anser to read several docs (i allready spent tons of time)
- suggest to try another distro (that's NOT a solution)
- suggest to reflash my sdcard (NOT a solution too)

Who got Qt-5.7/qtquickcontrols2/QML working on raspberrypi 2 through EGLFS utilizing the vc4???
Thank you very very much for every single breadcrumb...

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem. The eglfs_brcm backend of Qt is using the **vchiq** device, which is the video core device. That's the same device the **vc4-kms-v3d overlay** uses when you activate hw-acceleration in your **config.txt** within /boot. Therefore the mentioned device is already grabbed and you can't use it anymore. The solution is to comment the appropriate line in your config.txt: `# dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` and your eglfs will work as i described above. Please correct me, if sth is not formulated correctly. I hope i can save you time and grey hairs with that solution.

Comment: Same problem with out of the box 2017-08-16-raspbian-stretch on Pi3 model B. Removing vc4-kms-v3d  fixed my opengl es. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can also keep vc4-kms-v3d and instead ditch the proprietary OpenGL libraries, and use mesa instead

Comment: @SergioMartins How?

Comment: @NateS, When building Qt yourself ignore any instructions which mention /opt/vc/ and remove those lines from the mkspec. For the rpi3 there's a ready made mkspec (linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue.

It happens that when you use the opensource '**vc4-kms-v3d**' driver (as set in your config.txt), you cannot use the closed source drivers (**/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so** and **/opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so**, on your LD_PRELOAD string).

The error

```
failed to add service - already in use?
```

Indicates that, as I've just found out.

So, you may either comment the line on config.txt OR don't use the LD_PRELOAD strategy nor QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_brcm

Comment: I faced the same error on cross-compiled qt-5.5.1 for raspbian buster binaries. I had to leave out " -opengl es2 -egl -openvg" from the configure options for the QApplication constructor to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

dont use fakg in your config.txt
comment

```
# dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```